# jupyter notebook kernel error no 2, pointing to old directory

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, kernel

After I renamed username (Linux, ubuntu),
jupyter notebook kernel keeps showing error.

**FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/oldusername/ml/env/bin/python3'**

When I check kernel.json file of the kernel,
it points to the oldusername kernel

**"argv":
"/home/oldusername/ml/env/bin/python3".**

however jupyter kernelspec list directory shows no problem.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: rename user back to old name.

Comment: some tools have hardcoded locations and you would have to write script which will  replace it in text files when you see problem. But problem is when some file keeps it as compressed or hiden - then you can't replace it. So better rename user to old name and eventually create new user and create again virtual environmens.